# foreach-loop generates unwanted <br \>-tag, breaks javascript of canvas.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, foreach

I'm trying to replace manually typing in 2 arrays into canvas.js for dynamic chart creation, and in concept want to dynamically build the javascript with PHP.

The code actually works if I comment out this portion:

```
foreach($dataset as $x => $y){
echo "{label:\"$x\",y: $y},";
}
```

which would define x,y-Datapairs for the graph. So I have the canvas, but no Data on it.

This code here comes in front:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(\"canvasname\", {
      title:{
        text: \"Arbiträre Mengen ohne Zusammenhang über die Jahre\"              
      },
      data: [
        { 
         type: \"line\",
         dataPoints: [";
```

but parsed, the source looks like this:

```
 data: [              
        { 
         type: "line",
         dataPoints: [<br />
```

with the `<br />` breaking my Javascript, and generating no output.

I either need a way to get rid of the `<br>` before the browser accessing the javascript bit, or need to know what the heck went wrong here.
Tested it on my local Windows Apache installation and my Linux remote Apache webserver.

Here is the whole code for reference:

```
$dataset = array(2010 => 240, 2011 => 73, 2012 => 12,2013 => 240,2014 => 30);

include "make_graph.php";
make_graph();

<?php
function make_graph()
{
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(\"dingdong\", {
      title:{
        text: \"Arbiträre Mengen ohne Zusammenhang über die Jahre\"              
      },
      data: [//array of dataSeries              
        { //dataSeries object
         type: \"line\",
         dataPoints: [";

foreach($dataset as $x => $y){
    echo "{label:\"$x\",y: $y},";
    }

echo "]        
      }
        ]
        });

    chart.render();
  }
  </script>
  <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"canvasjs.min.js\"></script>
  <div id=\"dingdong\" style=\"height: 300px; width: 400px;\">
  </div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: havent you considered building the array first, then `json_encode`, then using it on javascript?

Comment: I can literally just type echo "{label:\"200\",y: 200},"; and get valid script, I just don't see where the <br> comes from when I try a foreach-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dont get why not just build it first (of course follow the rules of the API). Use `json_encode()`. Then simply concatenate the json string (since its a string). Consider this example: [**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/z5xCBL)

```
<?php

$dataset = array(2010 => 240, 2011 => 73, 2012 => 12, 2013 => 240 ,2014 => 30);
$new_dataset = array();
foreach($dataset as $key => $value) {
    $new_dataset[] = array('label' => $key, 'y' => $value);
}
$new_dataset = json_encode($new_dataset);

echo 
'
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("dingdong", {
          title:{
            text: "Arbiträre Mengen ohne Zusammenhang über die Jahre"              
          },
          data: [              
              {
                  type: "line",
                  dataPoints: '.$new_dataset.'
              }
              ]
        });

        chart.render();
    }
</script>        
';

?>

<div id="dingdong"></div>
```

Comment: Though it also works like this: 

$middle = "";
foreach($dataset as $x => $y){
    $middle .= "{label:\"$x\",y: $y},";
}
And then insert it where you need it.
echo "dataPoints: [".$middle."]";


I still did it in json now, if you guys say it it must be neccessary. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: @BismuthUupa well good to know it turned out well. your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Format the array to the desired structure and then use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
<?php

$dataset = array( 2010 => 240, 2011 => 73, 2012 => 12, 2013 => 240, 2014 => 30 );

$dataset = array_map( function( $a, $b ) {
    return array( 'label' => $a, 'y' => $b );
}, array_keys($dataset), array_values($dataset) );

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart( "dingdong", {
      title:{
        text: "Arbiträre Mengen ohne Zusammenhang über die Jahre"              
      },
      data: [{
         type: "line",
         dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataset); ?>   
      }]
    });
    chart.render();
  }

</script>
```